# hibernate HQL Query select

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i wanna transfer this code SQL to HQL
i try this code but it dosn't work

```
public Admin connect(String login, String password)
{
SessionFactory sessionFactory =createSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
  Admin admin=(Admin) session.createQuery(from admin where login_admin='"+login+"' and password_admin='"+password+"');
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return admin;
```

my class

```
public class Admin extends personne implements java.io.Serializable {
private String loginAdmin;
private String passwordAdmin;}
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: whats not working can you specify the error in detail ?

Comment: What does Admin look like? What error are you seeing?

Comment: Post your admin calss

Comment: is this syntaxe correct ???

Comment: Just because you are **using hibernate does not make you injection proof**. See this post for a start on HQL injection: http://blog.h3xstream.com/2014/02/hql-for-pentesters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Admin where loginAdmin= :login and password = :passwordAdmin");
query.setParameter("login", login);
query.setParameter("password", password );
Admin admin = (Admin)query.uniqueResult();
```

Creating the HQL query (or any other type of DB query that is) by concatenating Strings is a bad idea since that way you are opening up your system to SQL injections!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will Convert your HQL to SQL.And you can write HQL query as given below to get a particular object(or record). `createQuery()` expects HQL query not SQL query.
If your class is like  this

```
class Admin{
String loginAdmin;
String passwordAdmin;
}
```

Change your SQL query to HQL as given below

```
Admin admin=(Admin) session.createQuery
(from Admin where loginAdmin='"+login+"' and passwordAdmin='"+password+"').uniqueResult();
```

You can refer uniqueResult() method [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

In order to call sql queries call 
    session.createSQLQuery(sql query here);
So your code is wrong.

In order to call HQL queries call:

```
session.createQuery("from Admin where loginAdmin='"+login+"' and passwordAdmin='"+password+"'");
```

This is assuming the class is Admin with properties login and password